# SQL Conditional Update From Excel

Tags: sql, excel, oracle

I am trying to update my database using a query that pulls the changes from Excel.

The DB will look something like this:

Table PriceList:

> ID   ......PriceID  .......Price   ........PriceWithTax
>
> 1 ...........1      ..............100...............        110
>
> 1      ...........2...............      90         .................99
>
> 1      ...........3...............      80.................         88

The PriceID indicates that this item can have 3 different prices (for different customers).

What the TO BE excel file contains is:

> ItemCode  .........Description    .........Price1 .......Price2   .......Price3
>
> ABCD          ...................Steak         ..............100      .............90      ............80

So far, I can update 1 by 1, however I want to do it all in one query.

This is my **first part** to the query for inputting the Price1 Value - however it changes all values:

```
UPDATE  dbo.PriceList
SET     PriceList.fExclPrice = Price1
FROM        StockItem INNER JOIN PriceList ON StockItem.StockID = PriceList.StockID
INNER JOIN OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Update.xls;', 
'SELECT ItemCode, Description, Price1
FROM [Update$]')
ON StockItem.ItemCode COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = ItemCode
```

The **Second Part** is like this:

```
UPDATE  dbo.PriceList
SET     PriceList.fExclPrice = Price2
FROM        StockItem INNER JOIN PriceList ON StockItem.StockID = PriceList.StockID
INNER JOIN OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Update.xls;', 
'SELECT ItemCode, Description, Price2
FROM [Update$]')
ON StockItem.ItemCode COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = ItemCode Where PriceList.PriceID = 2
```

The Last part is for the PriceWithTax:

> Update PriceList SET  PriceWithTax = ROUND(fExclPrice * 1.14, 2)

What is the best way to combine these into 1 query?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with having 3 queries?

Comment: Because currently, with the existing process, the first query changes the other 3 prices. We also want to read in 1 query from a spreadsheet, not have to copy and paste every time.